# Getting Exception - "A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom." when using DropdownButton

Tags: flutter

I have a challenge similar to what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621388/a-renderflex-overflowed-by-infinity-pixels-on-the-bottom):

However, the answer didn't solve the problem. Now I am stuck. Here's my code:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<String> zipCodes = List<String>.from(snapshot.data);
  zipCodeValue = zipCodes[0];
  return Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 50,
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        items: zipCodes.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: dropDownStringItem,
            child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
          setState(() {
            zipCodeValue = newValueSelected;
          });
        },
        value: zipCodeValue,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I wrapped the DropdownButton widget in a container as recommended but not solved the issue.

I tried other answers from Stackoverflow questions but didn't sort out my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can't wrap a DropDownButton within a Column. I believe the challenge is:

> When a Column has one or more Expanded or Flexible children, and is placed in another Column, or in a ListView, or in some other context that does not provide a maximum height constraint for the Column, you will get an exception at runtime saying that there are children with non-zero flex but the vertical constraints are unbounded.[As noted here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Wrapping in DropDownButton in the Flexible widget worked.